# Matrix of complex linear transformation!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let T be a linear map from $\mathbb C \times \mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C \times \mathbb C$ defined by $T(z,w)=(z,0)$.

What is the matrix of the transformation . If it is a real vector space,i can easily do it .But complex vector space itself have (for example)${(0,1),(1,0)}$ as a basis but what is basis of complex vector space with higher dimensions?

how can elements of higher dimensional complex vector space as a linear combination of basis?.

Any hint is appreciated

Comment: It is very helpful if you suggest a general approach or reference rather than answer to the problem at the beginning of the question! THANKS!

Comment: Is $T$ from $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}?$

Comment: @Maam sorry , you are right ... i will edit it

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to write down the equation $T(z,w)=(z,0)$ in matrix form.
So for all $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ 
c  & d\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
z \\ w 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
z \\0 
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$ are the unknowns we must find. A good trick is to use simple values of $z$ and $w$ so that you get easy equations for $a,b,c,d$. For instance, take $z=1$, $w=0$ and also $z=0$, $w=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$T$ is a projection onto the first coordinate ( which is a complex number) or, if you prefer, is a projection onto a $2$-dimensional subspace of a $4$-dimensional space.

It is reasonable to work with complex numbers.... didn't you write $T$ operates on $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}?$ The matrix can be found as suggested by Ernie060 ( method) or simply guessed, and is:

\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 
0  & 0\end{bmatrix}